Importing the content of a text file in a text field in Postgres
I have a folder called Reports with several UTF-8 text files. Each file follows the next rule name:
userCode + '.txt'

I want to have a table with the next columns:
user_code        |   report
---------------------------------------------------
some user code   |   content of  userCode.txt

For example:
user_code        |   report
---------------------------------------------------
D3677234         |   'Born in blah blah ...... '
D4535535         |   'Traveled to blah blah ... '
 ....

where the content of D3677234.txt is 'Born in blah blah ...... '
and the content of   D4535535.txt is 'Traveled to blah blah ... '
So, I need a way to upload the content of those files into my table in Postgres directly from the Reports folder.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Write a script in your favorite programming language?

I was wondering if there is a faster approach, I just found pg_read_file... hmmm

That could work, when your database has access to these files. Use pg_ls_dir() to get all files in a directory
